# Android multiple resolution support

Tags: android, android-resources, android-resolution

I'm creating a game and I need to give the artist the PIXEL SIZE of the background images so he can draw them at photoshop/flash.

I want to support most mobiles and tablets.

Whats the sizes of background pics i need? and to what folder?

PLEASE(!) dont refer me to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
It has way to much information and i cant find the answer there.

I just need the image sizes of backgrounds (ALL SCREEN) in pixels..

thanks

Comment: I suggest you take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Gee, thanks. you're a true asset to this community

Comment: The TLDR page you didn't read seems to include a table that includes what the emulator supports, presumably with all the resolutions Google thought are worth testing against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Table Comparison]

Here is a table of typical resolutions. **However**, a best practice is to not target individual pixel densities, as there are a gazillion of Android devices in the wild, and all have different resolutions. So no matter how many background images you produce/include in your app, there will always be devices where the image looks bad/distorted. What you can do is choose a background color (or repeating texture) that fills the edges of the screen, and have a  centered image in the middle that is scaled by the Android system according to the screen resolution. That way, you'll always have a crisp, "full screen" image, no matter what resolution the device has.

Comment: This comes from the **forbidden Document**! It's banned! And the information is not in there anyways! ;)

Comment: Psst, don't tell him ;-P!

Comment: Thanks Nick, ill keep this in mind!

Comment: i saw it there, and i did tried to follow on the forbidden document.. 
my english is not perfect and its hard for me sometimes to follow on 900+ lines article for a silly answer. so it happens once in 3 months and i ask for help here in StackOF, and i get ppl (nm the names) downvoting and making offencive remarks :(